# Detecting and applying constraints automatically with Solr

Tags: solr

I want to implement smarter search solution for my users but there is something missing with faceted search and filter queries.

Lets take a look at use case. There are several car brands and models and lets say there is also color parameter.
What I want to do is, if user enters "bmw m5 black" to a textbox I want solr to catch brand category as "bmw", model category as "m5" and color category as "black" and apply those as filter query.
The idea come up from search technique when I saw google product search. 
Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

Solr won't do this "guessing" for you. You have to implement it client-side.

Comment: do you know any way to solve this issue elegantly. any suggestions?

Comment: @Burak Bayer: my guess is you'd have to write a custom SearchComponent, but ask on the solr-user and/or solr-dev mailing lists for guidance.